# How do I fill my dictionary values with the values from another dictionary where their keys are the same?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one dictionary (dictDemCLass) with a key but the values are all 0 and I plan to fill them with the values from another dictionary (dictAvgGrade).  I need to do so where the keys of the two dictionaries are the same.

```
dictAvgGrade = {k:sum(v)/4 for k,v in studentPerf.items()}

dictDemClass = {k:0 for k in classes}
```

When printed (dictAvgGrade is shortened):

```
print(dictAvgGrade)
{('Jeffery', 'male', 'junior'): 0.7749999999999999, ('Able', 'male', 'senior'): 0.8200000000000001, ('Don', 'male', 'junior'): 0.7974999999999999, ('Will', 'male', 'senior'): 0.7975000000000001}

print(dictDemClass)

{'junior': 0, 'senior': 0, 'sophomore': 0}
```

Ultimately I want to fill dictDemClass to show the average for each class. So that the output could look something like:

```
print(dictDemClass)

{'junior': 77.46, 'senior': 83.82, 'sophomore': 86.79}
```

Comment: So the final values in `dictDemClass` are the averages of all corresponding values in `dictAvgGrade`?

Comment: yes that's what im hoping to achieve, obviously the ones there at the end of my post are just an example

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to groups items in `dictAvgGrade` by "class" (i.e. junior, senior, etc.). Then you can compute the average for each group and add it to `dictDemClass`.

So for the example your posted, it can be something like the following:

```
from itertools import groupby

dictAvgGrade = {('Jeffery', 'male', 'junior'): 0.7749999999999999, ('Able', 'male', 'senior'): 0.8200000000000001, ('Don', 'male', 'junior'): 0.7974999999999999, ('Will', 'male', 'senior'): 0.7975000000000001}
dictDemClass = {'junior': 0, 'senior': 0, 'sophomore': 0}

def get_class(x):
    return x[0][2]

for k, g in groupby(sorted(dictAvgGrade.items(), key=get_class), key=get_class):
    group = list(g)
    class_avg = sum(x[1] for x in group)/len(group)
    dictDemClass[k] = class_avg

print(dictDemClass)
```

**Output**

```
{'senior': 0.8087500000000001, 'junior': 0.7862499999999999, 'sophomore': 0}
```

Comment: I might have been too vague, see my comment on the other response.  Id appreciate if you could give this another look

Comment: @JacobMyer As alex pointed out, can you please add example data and the expected output?

Comment: I added some more information, I think that should show you what my goal is

Comment: @JacobMyer I hope the updated answer is more helpful.

Comment: @JacobMyer Great! If this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

if you know that `dictAvgGrade` is always a subset of `dictDemClass` you can do this

```
dictDemClass.update(dictAvgGrade)
```

otherwise

if you are using python3 you can do something like this

```
for key in (dictDemClass.keys() & dictAvgGrade.keys()):
    dictDemClass[key] = dictAvgGrade[key]
```

if you are using python2 you can do something like this

```
for key in (set(dictDemClass.keys()) & set(dictAvgGrade.keys())):
    dictDemClass[key] = dictAvgGrade[key]
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  dictAvgGrade has all of the information that needs to go into dictDemClass, but its keys are in tuples and their is other information I hope to filter out by creating this new dictionary.  I need the v values of dictAvgGrade to fill the 0s of dictDemClass in the places where the keys from both of those dictionaries are equivalent

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure I understand, can you add examples of the two dictionaries and the desired result?

Comment: no worries, I made some changes. Hopefully that's easier to understand